# WPF Flowdocument - can't left-align ListItem markers

Tags: wpf, alignment, flowdocument, listitem

I've got a WPF FlowDocument with a list of MarkerType 'Upper Latin'.  It's looking like this:

[image]

Notice that the list item alignment is on the periods after the marker, but since the text is variable width, the D, E, and F look silly.  I would rather have the list markers be left aligned than right aligned, but I can't figure out how to do it.  TextAlignment on the List or ListItem makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using a table layout....Kinda clunky but it works